# Put a html element between div´s

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to put a `H2` element between `div` class productDescription;

My code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.productDescription').append($('<h2>'));
  $('.productDescription').prepend($('</h2>'));
});
```

```html
<div class="productDescription">Bota cano curto d</div>
```

I Need:

```
<div class="productDescription"><h2>Bota cano curto d </h2></div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wocwqjzg/ do you want it to be there when an element is clicked, or from the start?

Answer (score 2):

try that :

```
$('.productDescription').html("<h2>"+ $('.productDescription').html() +"</h2>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $h2 = $('<h2></h2>');
$h2.text('Whatever you want');
$('.productDescription').append($h2);
```

Answer (score 0):

this code has to work, it'll append a new h2 tag with whatever text in the .productDescription div

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.productDescription').append($('<h2>').html("Whatever"));
});
```